# Momentjs Convert total weeks in to month abbreviation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I got an bulk of serial numbers that include manufactured date as week.

example serial number:

`ABC D 08 05 1234`

- where **08** is year *(2008)*
- **05** is the week *(01 - 1st, 02 - second, 03 - third, 04 - fourth, 05 - fifth week etc..)*

I want to convert this in to **2008 Feb** format. Is there any easy way do this? please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week-year/

Comment: How about `moment().startOf('year').add(weekNo * 7, 'd').format('YYYY MMM')`?

Comment: That depends on how weeks are numbered. ISO 8601 weeks start on the Monday of the first Thursday of the year. There are other schemes such as the first Monday, the first of January, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

`[]` - escape characters in format strings

`YY` - Year

`ww` - week

```js
console.log(moment('ABC D 08 05 1234', '[ABC D] YY ww [1234]').format('YYYY MMM'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use appropriate values from the input string and [parsing tokens](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```js
let s = 'ABC D 08 05 1234';

console.log(
  moment(s.substr(6, 5), 'YY ww').format('YYYY MMM')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, that assumes that the weeks are numbered according to the scheme used by moment.js by default.

- 'w' uses the "locale" week, whatever that might be
- 'W' uses ISO 8601 week, which is specified to start on the Monday of the week with the first Thursday in the year

Comment: Its still outputs **2008 Jan**, which is correct. Jan in 2008 had 5 weeks... My bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **:**

```
var date=moment('ABC D 08 05 1234', '[] YY ww []').format('MMM YYYY');  

document.write(date);
```